# history -c; history -r run from script w/o shebang segfaults

Tags: bash

I'm on `Ubuntu 18.04`. My script:

```
history -c
history -r
```

It's executable; just plain running it with `<path-to-script>` (which defaults to `bash`) gives a `segmentation fault`.

All is well if I

- run with `bash <script>` instead, or
- add a shebang line `#!/usr/bin/env bash` at the top of the script, or
- remove either line from the script (`history -r` or `history -c`), or
- reverse their order.

So it's only when

- I run these two specific commands in conjunction,
- and in this order,
- *without* explicitly asking for `bash`

that I get the segfault.

This is baffling to me.

**Edit (bash version)**

`GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

**2nd edit (more info)**

The kernel:

```
$ uname -r
5.4.0-67-generic
```

`bash -c <path>` does not segfault.

`$SHELL` is `/bin/bash`

Finally, the strace output for `bash -c <path>`:

```
execve("/bin/bash", ["bash", "-c", "~/bin/sh.sh"], 0x7fff4b520938 /* 43 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55ddf345a000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=114382, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 114382, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f0e13a05000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\220\311\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=170784, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f0e13a03000
mmap(NULL, 2267936, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f0e135ce000
mprotect(0x7f0e135f3000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f0e137f3000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x25000) = 0x7f0e137f3000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\16\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14560, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2109712, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f0e133ca000
mprotect(0x7f0e133cd000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f0e135cc000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7f0e135cc000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20\35\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=2030928, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4131552, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f0e12fd9000
mprotect(0x7f0e131c0000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f0e133c0000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7f0e133c0000
mmap(0x7f0e133c6000, 15072, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f0e133c6000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f0e13a00000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f0e13a00740) = 0
mprotect(0x7f0e133c0000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f0e135cc000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f0e137f3000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x55ddf1d9c000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x7f0e13a21000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f0e13a05000, 114382)          = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK) = 3
close(3)                                = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x55ddf345a000
brk(0x55ddf347b000)                     = 0x55ddf347b000
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=3004224, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 3004224, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f0e12cfb000
close(3)                                = 0
getuid()                                = 548358
getgid()                                = 1112
geteuid()                               = 548358
getegid()                               = 1112
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
ioctl(-1, TIOCGPGRP, 0x7ffd3cfce424)    = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
sysinfo({uptime=1486259, loads=[5376, 2816, 416], totalram=8026251264, freeram=4826066944, sharedram=1769472, bufferram=1225637888, totalswap=16000217088, freeswap=15998644224, procs=390, totalhigh=0, freehigh=0, mem_unit=1}) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, 8) = 0
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="axiomatic", ...}) = 0
stat("$HOME", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/nsm", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/nsm/home", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("$HOME", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getpid()                                = 8925
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=26376, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 26376, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, 3, 0) = 0x7f0e13a1a000
close(3)                                = 0
getppid()                               = 8923
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("$HOME/bin/bash", 0x7ffd3cfce0a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("$HOME/.local/bin/bash", 0x7ffd3cfce0a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("$HOME/.local/usr/bin/bash", 0x7ffd3cfce0a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/axiomatic/data/perl5/bin/bash", 0x7ffd3cfce0a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("./bash", 0x7ffd3cfce0a0)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/sbin/bash", 0x7ffd3cfce0a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/bash", 0x7ffd3cfce0a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/sbin/bash", 0x7ffd3cfce0a0)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/bash", 0x7ffd3cfce0a0)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/sbin/bash", 0x7ffd3cfce0a0)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1113504, ...}) = 0
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1113504, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 548358
getegid()                               = 1112
getuid()                                = 548358
getgid()                                = 1112
access("/bin/bash", X_OK)               = 0
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1113504, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 548358
getegid()                               = 1112
getuid()                                = 548358
getgid()                                = 1112
access("/bin/bash", R_OK)               = 0
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1113504, ...}) = 0
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1113504, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 548358
getegid()                               = 1112
getuid()                                = 548358
getgid()                                = 1112
access("/bin/bash", X_OK)               = 0
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1113504, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 548358
getegid()                               = 1112
getuid()                                = 548358
getgid()                                = 1112
access("/bin/bash", R_OK)               = 0
getpid()                                = 8925
getpgrp()                               = 7911
ioctl(2, TIOCGPGRP, 0x7ffd3cfce2f4)     = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {sa_handler=0x55ddf1af0790, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, 8) = 0
ioctl(2, TIOCGPGRP, 0x7ffd3cfce2d4)     = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NPROC, NULL, {rlim_cur=30425, rlim_max=30425}) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=0x55ddf1af0790, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, 8) = 0
execve("$HOME/bin/sh.sh", ["$HOME/bin/sh.sh"], 0x55ddf3465d70 /* 42 vars */) = -1 ENOEXEC (Exec format error)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "$HOME/bin/sh.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
read(3, "history -c\nhistory -r\n", 128) = 22
close(3)                                = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
ioctl(2, TIOCGPGRP, 0x7ffd3cfce0b4)     = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {sa_handler=0x55ddf1af0790, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x55ddf1b09d30, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
ioctl(2, TIOCGPGRP, 0x7ffd3cfce424)     = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=0x55ddf1af0790, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {sa_handler=0x55ddf1af0790, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=0x55ddf1b09d30, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x55ddf1b09d30, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, 8) = 0
stat("$HOME", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/nsm", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/nsm/home", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
stat("$HOME", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getpid()                                = 8925
getppid()                               = 8923
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("$HOME/bin/bash", 0x7ffd3cfce0a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("$HOME/.local/bin/bash", 0x7ffd3cfce0a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("$HOME/.local/usr/bin/bash", 0x7ffd3cfce0a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/axiomatic/data/perl5/bin/bash", 0x7ffd3cfce0a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0700, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("./bash", 0x7ffd3cfce0a0)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/sbin/bash", 0x7ffd3cfce0a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/local/bin/bash", 0x7ffd3cfce0a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/sbin/bash", 0x7ffd3cfce0a0)  = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/bin/bash", 0x7ffd3cfce0a0)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/sbin/bash", 0x7ffd3cfce0a0)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1113504, ...}) = 0
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1113504, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 548358
getegid()                               = 1112
getuid()                                = 548358
getgid()                                = 1112
access("/bin/bash", X_OK)               = 0
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1113504, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 548358
getegid()                               = 1112
getuid()                                = 548358
getgid()                                = 1112
access("/bin/bash", R_OK)               = 0
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1113504, ...}) = 0
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1113504, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 548358
getegid()                               = 1112
getuid()                                = 548358
getgid()                                = 1112
access("/bin/bash", X_OK)               = 0
stat("/bin/bash", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1113504, ...}) = 0
geteuid()                               = 548358
getegid()                               = 1112
getuid()                                = 548358
getgid()                                = 1112
access("/bin/bash", R_OK)               = 0
getpid()                                = 8925
getpgrp()                               = 7911
ioctl(2, TIOCGPGRP, 0x7ffd3cfce2f4)     = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, {sa_handler=0x55ddf1af0790, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, {sa_handler=0x55ddf1af0790, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0x7f0e13018040}, 8) = 0
ioctl(2, TIOCGPGRP, 0x7ffd3cfce2d4)     = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, NULL, [], 8)  = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "$HOME/bin/sh.sh", O_RDONLY) = 3
stat("$HOME/bin/sh.sh", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0700, st_size=22, ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, 0x7ffd3cfce3b0)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
read(3, "history -c\nhistory -r\n", 80) = 22
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = 0
prlimit64(0, RLIMIT_NOFILE, NULL, {rlim_cur=1024, rlim_max=1024*1024}) = 0
fcntl(255, F_GETFD)                     = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
dup2(3, 255)                            = 255
close(3)                                = 0
fcntl(255, F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC)         = 0
fcntl(255, F_GETFL)                     = 0x8000 (flags O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat(255, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0700, st_size=22, ...}) = 0
lseek(255, 0, SEEK_CUR)                 = 0
read(255, "history -c\nhistory -r\n", 22) = 22
openat(AT_FDCWD, "$HOME/.history", O_RDONLY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=55, ...}) = 0
read(3, "#+1573149273\npwd\n#+1573149274\nls"..., 55) = 55
close(3)                                = 0
read(255, "", 22)                       = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, [CHLD], [], 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, [], NULL, 8) = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: Which bash version? What kernel version do you have? `This is baffling to me.` I guess  your file get's executed by kernel as an ELF executable. Which causes strange things to happen.

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Does running `bash -c '/the/path'` also segfaults? Would you be able to post `strace -ff bash -c '/the/path/to/file'`? What is the output of `echo $SHELL`?

Comment: It's not guaranteed that you can run things without shebangs (or magic for a binary type your local kernel recognizes) as executables _at all_. Relying on undefined behavior is a bad idea in general.

Comment: ...if you came here with a C question about why code written using practices that are undefined behavior per the C spec crashes, they'd tell you "go away and write your code to be using only defined behavior". A similar answer doesn't strike me as inappropriate here.

Comment: That said, if you get an identical failure from `sh yourscript` or `exec -a sh bash yourscript`, there's your explanation.

Comment: Well, executing with `sh` will error out for the simpler reason that `sh` doesn't know what `history` is, so that won't do much. I will update the post with answers to the questions in the latest comment by @KamilCuk

Comment: @grobber, some shells use `sh` as the default interpreter when there's no shebang. I'd need to go find the source to the specific version of bash you're looking at to know if it's one of them. (As described above, the behavior is undefined; a shell is free to use itself as said interpreter, to use `sh` as the interpreter, to refuse to execute the file at all, to kill your puppy, etc etc).

Comment: That said, `exec -a sh bash` was suggested as a test case to check for a reason: It gets you `bash`, which _does_ have a `history` command, but executed with an `argv[0]` that says it needs to be in POSIX-compatibility mode.

Comment: I understand it *might* be using `sh`, but it doesn't seem to: if it did, it would simply fail to find `history`. I also understand the behavior is undefined, but I am still curious as to what is going on.

Comment: Understood, but we don't handle curiosity-based questions here; we handle _practical, answerable_ questions (quoting https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). If it isn't practical to do something in production code, "don't do that; do this other thing instead" is all the answer that's needed. See [What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394/what-is-the-rationale-for-closing-why-questions-on-a-language-design)

Comment: Ah, I'd missed the `bash` at the end of `exec -a sh bash`. The results from that are dire: executing even an empty script with that command closes my ssh connection (this is not a local machine).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to instruct you to run that in a subshell. `(exec -a sh bash yourscript)` -- that way it won't kill your parent process.

Comment: `(exec -a sh bash <script>)` does nothing worrying: no complaints, and `$?` is 0 afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash has a bunch of magic to try to run scripts without shebang lines or other executable magic, even though the operating system will (correctly!) refuse to run them itself. Handling of these scripts is historically problematic/buggy -- if you read through bash's changelog, you'll see fixes to numerous bugs specific to their management.

Quoting several of them:

> ```
> z.  Fixed a bug that caused the shell to close process subsitution file
>   descriptors when executing a script without the `#!' leading line.
> ```

> ```
> a.  `exec -a foo' now sets $0 to `foo' in an executable shell script without a
>   leading #!.
> ```

> ```
> b.  Fixed startup so posixly_correct is retained across subshells begun to
>   execute scripts without a leading `#!'.
> ```

> ```
> q.  Fixed a bug that caused subshells started to run executable shell scripts
>   without a leading `#!' to incorrectly inherit an argument list preceding
>   a shell builtin (like such a script called from a script sourced with `.',
>   where there were variable assignments preceding the `.' command)
> ```

> ```
> y.  Fixed a couple of problems with shell scripts without a leading `#!'
>     being executed out of shell functions that could cause core dumps if
>     such a script attempted to execute `return'.
> ```

> ```
> tt. Fixed a bug that caused restricted shell mode to be set inappropriately
>   when trying to execute a shell script without a leading `#!'.
> ```

> ```
> w.  Fixed a bug that caused subshells forked to interpret executable
>     scripts without a leading `#!' to not reinitialize the values of
>     the shell options.
> ```

...and that's just the ones that came up before I got tired of copying-and-pasting from the changelog.

Writing scripts without shebangs is entirely impractical; you don't know how they'll be executed, and you're opening yourself up to a range of shell implementation bugs that wouldn't exist otherwise. Just Say No.

Comment: OK, thank you. Given that it seems I may have embarked on a fool's errand here, I'll accept this answer. I'll be watching for any other insights though.